# Gradient estimate on heat equation

Tags: inequality, heat-equation

*Consider the following heat equation on $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ with smooth boundary and $v(x)\in L^2(\Omega)$
$$
\begin{cases}
    u_t - \Delta u = 0 & \text{in } \Omega\times(0,+\infty) \\
    u(x,t) = 0 & \text{on }\partial\Omega\times(0,+\infty)\\
    u(x,0) = v(x) & \text{in }\Omega\times\{t=0\}
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that there exists a constant $C=C(\Omega, d)>0$ such that
$$
\Vert \nabla u\Vert^2
\leq 
\dfrac{C}{t}\Vert v\Vert^2
$$
where $\nabla = \nabla_x$ and
$$
\Vert f\Vert^2 := \int_{\Omega}|f|^2dx \quad (L^2(\Omega) \text{ norm})
$$*

**Here is my attempt on this problem:**
Using energy function, it is not difficult to show that for all $t>0$,
$$
\Vert u\Vert
\leq 
\Vert v\Vert
$$
We are going to prove that
$$
t\Vert \nabla u\Vert^2
\leq 
C\Vert u\Vert^2
$$
for some constant $C(\Omega,d)>0$. To show this is true, take the derivative with respect to $t$ of both sides, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2 
+ 2t\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla u_t dx 
\leq 
2C\int_{\Omega} uu_tdx 
\tag{1}
$$
Using some derivative manipulation along with Green's identity, we have
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\Omega}uu_tdx 
    &= \Vert u\Vert\dfrac{d}{dt}(\Vert u\Vert)\\
    %
    \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2dx 
    &= \int_{\Omega}u\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\mathbf{n}}dS
    - \int_{\Omega}u\Delta udx 
    = -\int_{\Omega}uu_tdx \\
    &= -\Vert u\Vert\dfrac{d}{dt}(\Vert u\Vert)\\
    %
    \int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla u_t
    &= \Vert\nabla u\Vert\dfrac{d}{dt}(\Vert\nabla u\Vert)
\end{align*}
Plug the above three manipulations to (1), we have
$$
2t\Vert\nabla u\Vert\dfrac{d}{dt}(\Vert\nabla u\Vert) 
\leq (2C + 1)\Vert u\Vert\dfrac{d}{dt}(\Vert u\Vert)
\tag{2}
$$
Now I'm going to prove (2) is true by changing $t$ to $s$, then integrate both side with respect to $s$ on range $[0, t]$,
$$
2\int_0^t s\Vert\nabla u(\cdot,s)\Vert\dfrac{d}{ds}(\Vert\nabla u(\cdot,s)\Vert)ds
\leq 
(2C + 1)\int_0^t \Vert u(\cdot,s)\Vert\dfrac{d}{ds}(\Vert u(\cdot,s)\Vert)ds
$$
It can be shown using integration by part that
$$
LHS = 
\dfrac{1}{2}t\Vert\nabla u(\cdot,t)\Vert^2 
- \int_0^t\Vert\nabla u(\cdot,s)\Vert^2 ds
$$
and
$$
RHS = \left(C + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)
(\Vert u(\cdot,t)\Vert^2 - \Vert v(\cdot)\Vert^2)
$$
Now I'm struggling on proving $LHS\leq RHS$, maybe my method doesn't hold true since it envolve a lot of integration and derivation of inequality. What should I do next?

Comment: Do you know some spectral theory for the heat equation?

Comment: @MaoWao Is it a part of the eigenvalue problem in PDE? For now I haven't had a good research about it, but later I will take a deep dive into.

Comment: Yes, it is related to eigenvalue problems. You can write the solution as $u(x,t)=\sum_k e^{-t\lambda_k}\langle\phi_k,v\rangle \phi_k(x)$, where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues and $\phi_k$ are the eigenfunctions of the (Dirichlet) Laplacian on $\Omega$. This reduces your problem to showing $\lambda e^{-2t\lambda}\leq C/t$ for$\lambda\geq 0$, which is of course elementary. But maybe someone else finds a solution that is more in line with your idea.

Comment: @MaoWao Interesting, and the same time much more elegance approach. I think I will take a look at your idea since mine is way to complicated. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MaoWao Do you have any documentation about the representation $u(x,t)=\sum_k e^{-t\lambda_k}\langle\phi_k,v\rangle\phi_k(x)$? I want to take a good research of it but so far I haven't found any good resource.